# Mysql not updating the avg function of same table different column by trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to update a specific column that is `column_2` by taking the  average of rows of  `column_1` values  where `column_3 =` value

but it gives a error

My code

`Error: Can't update table 'moving_average' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`

```
delimiter $$

Create TRIGGER takeaverage AFTER insert ON moving_table 
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN        
update moving_table b, (select avg(price) avg_ from moving_table ) v
set
  b.moving_avg = v.avg_price;


END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, as per the [documentaion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html):

> A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already
>   being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the
>   function or trigger.

I would rather write a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger and update the `:New.moving_avg` with the average of existing rows and the new `price`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply can you give me a specific query as an example